# I have this external geojson file. i would like to loop and echo the properties object (e.g "Name" "Easting" "Northing"). i dont were am getting wrong

Tags: php, html, json, performance, geojson

{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Trial",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Muwaya Pri. Sch", "Easting": 686607.293, "Northing": 8561595.506 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 686607.293, 8561595.50599999912 ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Munkulungwe Pri. Sch", "Easting": 690206.558, "Northing": 8550186.399 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 690206.558, 8550186.399 ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Fiwale Pri.Sch", "Easting": 685977.67, "Northing": 8539029.88 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 685977.67, 8539029.88 ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Mwatishi School", "Easting": 702707.723, "Northing": 8554903.974 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 702707.723, 8554903.97399999946 ] } }
]
}

CODE

```
              <?php$getfile = file_get_contents('test.Geojson');  ?>
              <?php$jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);  ?>

           <?php foreach ($jsonfile->features as $index => $obj): ?>
            <?php echo $obj->Name; ?>
            <?php echo $obj->Northing; ?>
           <?php echo $obj->Eastinglink; ?>
```

Comment: It would help to format your data and show the code you have tried with an explanation of where it is going wrong.

Comment: <?php
$getfile = file_get_contents('test.Geojson');
$jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);
?>
<
        <?php foreach ($jsonfile->features as $index => $obj): ?>
           
                <?php echo $obj->Name; ?>
                <?php echo $obj->Northing; ?>
               <?php echo $obj->Eastinglink; ?>

Comment: You're using `features` instead of `properties` - If I were you I'd go back to read the PHP basics and get familiar with methods such as var_dump() or print_r(), then read about json_decode - Good luck. https://www.php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All required properties are under properties key. change your code to read below.

```
echo $obj->properties->NAME ;
echo $obj->properties->Northing; 
echo $obj->properties->Eastinglink;
```